# DMA_SxNDTR sets itself to max value (65535) after stream enabled

Tags: stm32, dma, usart

I'm trying to use DMA with USART1 to receive data in stm32f205xx series. After initialization sequence I read NDTR register and it has value 4, exactly what I put there. But after stream enabled value of NDTR is 65535.

```
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA2EN;
DMA2_Stream2->CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_EN;
while(DMA2_Stream2->CR & DMA_SxCR_EN);
DMA2_Stream2->PAR = (uint32_t)&(USART1->DR);
DMA2_Stream2->M0AR = (uint32_t)&test_array[0];
DMA2_Stream2->NDTR = 4;
uint32_t temp = DMA2_Stream2->NDTR; // HERE 4
DMA2_Stream2->CR |= (4<<25);        //ch4 for stream 2
DMA2_Stream2->CR |= (3<<16);        //very high priority
DMA2_Stream2->CR |= (1<<10);        //increment memory
DMA2_Stream2->CR |= (1<<5);         //flow control
DMA2_Stream2->CR |= (1<<4);         //transmit complete interrupt enable
DMA2_Stream2->CR |= (1<<2)|(1<<1);  //all interrupts available
DMA2_Stream2->FCR |= (1<<7);  //all interrupts available

NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream2_IRQn);
uart1_init();
DMA2_Stream2->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;


temp = DMA2_Stream2->NDTR; //HERE 65535
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was wrong 
DMA2_Stream2->CR |= (1<<5);         //flow control
read reference manual Flow Control

Answer (score 1):

This is a symptom of setting the DMA configuration register to peripheral flow control, rather than "normal" flow control.

- In "normal" flow control, it is `DMA_SxNDTR` that sets the number of data blocks to be transferred and is decremented each time an item is transferred.  the transfer is complete when DMA_SxNDTR reaches 0.
- when using "peripheral" flow control, the peripheral signals the end of the transfer to the DMA controller through other means.

From STM32F767 reference manual **RM0410 section 8.2** (for a different MCU, but having similar peripheral hardware)

> – DMA flow controller: the number of data items to be transferred is software programmable
>   from 1 to 65535
>
> – Peripheral flow controller: the number of data items to be transferred is unknown
>   and controlled by the source or the destination peripheral that signals the end of
>   the transfer by hardware

Also see section **8.3.16 Flow controller** in the same manual